# NSScrollView in a NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollView inside an NSWindow, but it seems to be disabled.  It *looks* like it would work, but the scrollbars are **unresponsive** to the mouse or the scroll wheel.

When I put the exact same NSScrollView inside a window on a new XCode project, it works perfect.  There is something about the way I am making the window that is preventing the scroll from working.

I've been able to simplify it to this example:

```
//Make a window
NSWindow* myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(300, 300, 300, 300)
                                       styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
                                       backing:NSBackingStoreRetained
                                       defer:NO];

//Make a scroll view
NSScrollView *scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300)];
[scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[scrollview setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];
[myWindow setContentView:scrollview];

//Add something big to the scroll view
NSButton* btn = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 600, 900)] autorelease];
[scrollview setDocumentView:btn];

//Show the window
[NSApp arrangeInFront:self];
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem, based on some experimentation I just did, seems to be with specifying `NSBackingStoreRetained`. The docs say:

> You should not use this mode. It combines the limitations of `NSBackingStoreNonretained` with the memory use of `NSBackingStoreBuffered`.

They also say:

> In Mac OS X 10.5 and later, requests for retained windows will result in the window system creating a buffered window, as that better matches actual use.

This does not seem to be accurate; switching the `buffer:` argument to `NSBackingStoreBuffered` made the window and scroll view behave as expected for me. (The docs also say not to use `NSBackingStoreNonRetained`, and indeed, it seemed to have problems similar to `NSBackingStoreRetained`.)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. NSBackingStoreBuffered fixed it. Thank you so much.  It also fixed a cascade of other flaky issues with some views in that NSWindow.