# No scrolling or user interaction in new NSWindow with NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsscrollview

I am building an application (without interface builder!) which 'lives' in the NSStatusBar; when you click on an icon in the StatusBar a NSWindow with a NSScrollView appears. The window appears but it seems that something is preventing user interaction with the ScrollView

To find out where the problem comes from I also added my view to the main windows contentView in the AppDelegate, strange thing is that the scrollview is interactive in the MainWindow... Anyone knows why it doesn't work in my new Window?

This is the code I use to create the new TTDropDownWindow:

```c
- (void)openWindow {
    // Dropdown
    if (self.dropDownWindow == nil) {
        self.dropDownWindow = [[TTDropDownWindow alloc] init];
        self.dropDownWindow.releasedWhenClosed = NO;
        self.dropDownWindow.contentView = self.view;
        self.dropDownWindow.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
        self.dropDownWindow.delegate = self;
        self.dropDownWindow.alphaValue = 1;
        self.dropDownWindow.hasShadow = NO;
        self.dropDownWindow.opaque = NO;
    }

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    NSRect statusBarContentRect = self.statusBarItemView.window.frame;
    NSPoint statusBarOriginPoint = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(statusBarContentRect), NSMinY(statusBarContentRect));

    NSRect screenFrame = self.dropDownWindow.screen.frame;

    NSRect dropDownContentRect = NSZeroRect;
    dropDownContentRect.size.width = DROP_DOWN_WIDTH;
    dropDownContentRect.size.height = DROP_DOWN_HEIGHT;
    dropDownContentRect.origin.x = statusBarOriginPoint.x - DROP_DOWN_WIDTH / 2;
    dropDownContentRect.origin.y = screenFrame.size.height - DROP_DOWN_HEIGHT - NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar.thickness;

    [self.dropDownWindow setFrame:dropDownContentRect display:YES];
    [self.dropDownWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
```

This is the implementation of TTDropDownWindow:

```c
#import "TTDropDownWindow.h"
#import "WFConstants.h"

@implementation TTDropDownWindow

- (id) init
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, DROP_DOWN_WIDTH, DROP_DOWN_HEIGHT) styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreRetained defer:NO];
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}


@end
```

And this is the code that creates the View and the ScrollView

```c
#import "TTStatusBarDropDownView.h"
#import "TTTestView.h"

@implementation TTStatusBarDropDownView

@synthesize dropDownTableViewData = dropDownTableViewData_;


- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
        imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"background-dropdown"];
        [self addSubview:imageView];

        // first create a view to put in a ScrollView
        NSView *scrollViewHolder = [[TTTestView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(19, 98, 414, 543) andColor:[NSColor yellowColor]];
        [self addSubview:scrollViewHolder];

        // create the scrollView
        NSScrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 414, 543)];
        scrollView.hasVerticalRuler = YES;
        scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
        [scrollViewHolder addSubview:scrollView];

        // TTTestView is just a NSView with a background drawing
        TTTestView *theViewThatScrolls = [[TTTestView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 10000) andColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
        [theViewThatScrolls addSubview:[[TTTestView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 8000) andColor:[NSColor grayColor]]];

        [scrollView setDocumentView:theViewThatScrolls];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I dont code for mac OS, only for the iOS mobile devices, but maybe is your ScrollView not the firstResponder?

Comment: Do you need to set that programmatically?

Comment: I think not, but i had have some situations where my ViewObject doesnt were the firstResponder and therefore I had to set them explixit. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might change NSBackingStoreRetained to NSBackingStoreBuffered as stated over here:
[NSScrollView in a NSWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553883/nsscrollview-in-a-nswindow)

Comment: This solved the problem, so whenever you create a window! Use the NSBackingStoreBuffered mode! Thanks for helping!